# Select inserting random phantom option in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a select:

```
<select name="dateFields.month" data-ng-model="dateFields.month" placeholder="Month" class="form-control" ng-change="checkDate()" ng-disabled="disableFields">
   <option ng-show="!dateFields.month" value="" translate="yes">#Apply.Month</option>
   <option ng-repeat="month in months" value="{{month.value}}" ng-selected="month.value == dateFields.month">{{month.name | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

The ng-repeat loops through this array:

```
this.months = [
  { value: 1, name: '#Common.January' },
  { value: 2, name: '#Common.February' },
  { value: 3, name: '#Common.March' },
  { value: 4, name: '#Common.April' },
  { value: 5, name: '#Common.May' },
  { value: 6, name: '#Common.June' },
  { value: 7, name: '#Common.July' },
  { value: 8, name: '#Common.August' },
  { value: 9, name: '#Common.September' },
  { value: 10, name: '#Common.October' },
  { value: 11, name: '#Common.November' },
  { value: 12, name: '#Common.December' }
];
```

When the page is loaded, if the dateFields.month is not set the default option is visible:

```
<option ng-show="!dateFields.month" value="" translate="yes">#Apply.Month</option>
```

When the dateFields.month is set then the above option is invisible but instead I get this phantom option appearing out of nowhere:

```
<option value="? number:1 ?"></option>
```

I suspect that is because `dateFields.month` is equal to the value 1 instead of `{ value: 1, name: '#Common.January' }` but not sure how to fix that because angular is supposed to handle the binding to the array and the selection?

I tried binding the ng-model to `dateFields.month.value` but that didn't work. I get the error: `Cannot create property 'value' on number '1'`

Note: I have a few other selects that are similar construct and they behave correctly. Only this one does that.

### UPDATE

We have a plunk

https://plnkr.co/edit/xIdJ9tFSrcWQ4bKmUvX9?p=preview

Comment: If other similar selects work, then it could be the array in months with a phantom value or some other typo we can't see, could you possibly repeat the problem in a plunkr?

Comment: It's one of those where creating a working plunkr would take longer than finding the solution

Comment: I know the feeling, have you tried ng-hide="!dateFields.month" on the repeated options

Comment: I am sure it would work if there was a way to do "track by month.value" but that doesn't work on ng-repeat, only on ng-options which I can't have because I want the translation thing.
It keeps adding a phantom value equal to the hash of the object. So annoying

Comment: I managed to produce a working plunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using ng-model and binding it to dateFields.Month.  Since dateFields.month represents just a month.value and not the whole month object, you need to reflect that in your ng-options, which you can use instead of ng-repeat.

```
<select name="dateFields.month" ng-model="dateFields.month" ng-options="month.value as month.name | translate for month in months" placeholder="Month" class="form-control" ng-change="checkDate()" ng-disabled="disableFields">
  <option value="" translate>#Apply.Month</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/kjD4EQocBXiDYDuV7I6e?p=preview) with translations working.

Comment: No. That's how I used to have it and even though that works it's not a suitable solution because I want to be able to translate the options with a custom attribute so I need the value of the option to be: {{month.name | translate}}

Comment: This approach would work if you translated the month names in the controller code.

Comment: @Nick - you can do your translations by applying a filter to month.name.  I've updated my answer to reflect proper translation.

Comment: I changed it to this: ng-options="month.value as month.name for month in months | translate for month in months"

(remember the ng-options="month.value as month.name for month in months") was the original implementation that worked correctly.

Now I get : Token 'for' is an unexpected token at column 20 of the expression [months | translate for month in months] starting at [for month in months]

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it with putting the value as "0" for the default option "#Apply.Month", and on initialization of the controller assign "dateFields.month" as '0'. this will solve your problem

Comment: But the month option needs to have ng-show="!dateFields.month" and I can't add that if I bind to a month collection that contains the default option... did you see the plunk?